# R Count monthly frequency of occurrence between date range

Tags: r, date, dplyr, count, frequency

```
x <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
            Line_name = c("AB", "CD", "AB", "CD"),
            start_dt = c("12/1/2020", "2/1/2021", "2/1/2021", "3/1/2021"),
            end_dt = c("4/1/2021", "4/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "4/1/2021"))

ID Line_name start_dt   end_dt
1        AB  12/1/2020 4/1/2021
2        CD  2/1/2021 4/1/2021
3        AB  2/1/2021 3/1/2021
4        CD  3/1/2021 4/1/2021
```

I have a dataframe that looks likes this. It has items that is used within date range (start date to end date). I need to count frequency of use of each item for every month. The resulting output would look something like this.

```
    Line_name Jan2021 Feb2021 Mar2021 Apr2021
1        AB       1       2       2       1
2        CD       0       1       2       2
```

In Jan, only AB was used. For that ID 1, the date ranges from Jan to April. So we would need to count that row for every month from Jan to April.

I am not sure how I can do it. I was thinking for instance January, I would check if 1/1/2021 date falls within start_dt and end_dt and if that condition is true than count.
(date %within% interval(start_dt, end_dt))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to get a sequence of dates by `month` between the 'start_dt', and 'end_dt' columns with `map2` into a `list`, then `unnest` the `list` column, get the `count` and reshape back from 'long' to 'wide' with `pivot_wider`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>% 
   transmute(Line_name, Year_month = map2(mdy(start_dt), mdy(end_dt),
      ~ format(seq(.x, .y, by = '1 month'), '%b%Y'))) %>%
   unnest(c(Year_month)) %>%
   count(Line_name, 
        Year_month = factor(Year_month, levels = unique(Year_month))) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Line_name Jan2021 Feb2021 Mar2021 Apr2021
  <chr>       <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1 AB              1       2       2       1
2 CD              0       1       2       2
```

Comment: What if I wanted to see the counts only for 2021. In my dataset there are row which have date range from 2018 to 2021 but I am only trying to see the 2021 data. I have updated the data in the post. Even though the start date is before 2021, I still want to count if it flows through to 2021.

Comment: @utsabshrestha then, you may need to subset after creating the `seq` and before the `format` or after the `unnest` step, using substring i.e. `%>% filter(substring(Year_month, 4) == 2021) %>% count(..`